# Idea about how to model a building using OpenGL/GLUT?

Tags: c++, opengl, freeglut

I'm new to graphics, and I have to make a model of a building for an assignment using only GLUT or OpenGL.

Basically the school building's model( only the exterior portion) is to be made, and I have no clue where to start. Upto now I have drawn polygons, other shapes using GLUT, nothing in which there are multiple shapes. All the drawing upto now is using lines, or points, or polygons and mathematics.

Could you please give me an idea of how to go about it?

Update: I just want to know what steps I can follow to get it done. Some reference links would be awesome!

Comment: What have you tried?  Please try to ask a specific question.  You're unlikely to get someone to do your homework for you.

Comment: I just want to get an idea on how it will be done, maybe the steps to getting it done, some reference materials etc.

Comment: Model the building in a 3D modeller like Blender or 3DS Max, then export it into a easy to parse file format (e.g. .OBJ), render it from there. If your teacher/professor actually requires you to _code_ the model in OpenGL I'd gladly help you telling him off, that this is very, very bad style. If this is still insisted upon export your model into C arrays for data storage and access those arrays. It's in the code then ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about what you want your building to look like, and think about what kind of triangles you need to render in order to make that. You can either draw the entire thing in some sort of modelling software, and then import it into OpenGL, or you can come up with the triangles/textures yourself and do it by hand in OpenGL.

The exterior of the building will probably have a similar texture on the whole thing (brick, etc), and then there will be windows, doors, and a roof. Maybe some sort of sign that says "School Building". Take this all into account, what exactly you want your building to look like, and then think about what textures you will need to draw these things.

For example, say you're doing a brick building that is in the shape of a box, with a door and a few windows. I'd use one texture for the brick, and first draw an entire wall of brick. Then, I'd use a grey/blue looking texture for the window, and draw it over the brick wall. Then I'd do the same (different texture) for the door.

Just think about the design, and then just try things out - experiment. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You could use modeling programs to create your model, and then use tools such as [COLLADA](http://www.collada.org/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page) to get your model into OpenGL.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with hand-coding a complex object like that is that it takes a great number of lines of code just to define the vertices of the object.

People usually use 3D modeler software to build complex 3D objects, like Maya, 3DSMax or Blender and then export them in a format to be read into your OpenGL application.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a simillar homework. I did it by creating the models with Google SketchUp, then export the models to .3ds file and use my program to render it. 
I choose Google SketchUp because it's the easiest to use among those tool I tried. Plus, they had a discount for students. You could also use Blender, which is free but take too much time to learn IMHO. 3dsMax is too expensive to pay for a homework. 
To load the model into my program, I used [Assimp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/index.html) library.